# можно ли строку получить как int?

Tags: c++, c

есть такой define

```
#define HOME_NET   0
```

и два массива.

```
char a[4];
a[HOME_NET] = 4;
char str[] = "HOME_NET";
```

хотел написать такой define

```
#define VAR(XXX) XXX
...
printf ( "%d\n", a[VAR(str)] );
```

Думал что возможно строку представить как int, ну то есть define HOME_NET есть, и он будет определяться в VAR как int. Можно ли строку использовать как define HOME_NET  0?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Очевидно, что преобразовать строковой литерал в директиву препроцессора, а затем заменить ее на 0 не выйдет. Зато выйдет подставить в строку не название директивы препроцессора, а ее значение, и получить `"0"`, которую можно без проблем перевести в число как предлагают в вопросе-дубликате. В крайнем случае составить словарь текст -> число и искать по нему, но это уже будет явно из другой оперы.

Comment: @VTT о, спасибо, вот так понятно, буду пробывать.

Comment: @VTT а как сделать такой define, чтобы строку преобразовал в число, которое определено в #define HOME_NET  0?

Comment: @xverizex Может, наоборот, число в строку? Для этого есть препроцессорный оператор "решётка". Объявите макросы `#define STRINGIFY2(x) #x` и `#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY2(x)`, и используете их как `char str[] = STRINGIFY(HOME_NET);`. К чему эта матрёшка: STRINGIFY превращает литерал `HOME_NET` в литерал `0`, а STRINGIFY2 превращает `0` в `"0"`

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev а если строку "HOME_NET" передать в STRINGIFY, то можно как нибудь получить значение define HOME_NET 0 ? Мне надо строку преобразовать в индекс массива, чтобы адресовываться к нужной переменной, считывая из файла переменные такие как HOME_NET.